# What ports does Warhammer 40,000: Space Marine use?

Tags: ps3, networking, warhammer-40k-space-marine

I can't seem to find any official information of which ports Warhammer 40,000: Space Marine uses. I own the game for the PS3 and need to forward the ports.
Even though it works without forwarding anything, it takes between five and twenty minutes to get a match like this.

Comment: If you have UPnP enabled, the ports will be forwarded automatically.  If it already works, it's not because of ports - the reason is probably just that not many people play multiplayer Space Marines on PS3.

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft: There are several games that needs specific ports forwarded, or router firewall completely switched off for full functionality. Besides, I'm certain there's enough players online just under two weeks after official release.

Comment: Also dependent on your connection speed and whether you are wired/wireless.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, which was solved by setting my PS3 as the DMZ in the router (effectively opening all ports).

In regards to security, this should be fine, I've had my PS3 as the DMZ since I bought it and have not had, nor heard of any issues doing so.